# How to store xpath in a variable and use that variable in an another xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

storing an xpath in a variable, and calling the variable in other xpath sentence

example.xml

```
<Variable Name="LC_F_DPN"> 
    <Path>//ZC_area/Block/Next_block/Variant</Path> 
    <Variable_type>DPN</Variable_type>
    <Class_name>Point</Class_name>
</Variable>
```

myxslcode.xsl

````
    <xsl:variable name="MyPath" select="//Variable/Path"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$MyPath[Index_on_line_section =current()/@VARIANT_RANK and Line_section_id =current()/$LC_ID]/../../Id"/>
</xsl:if>```

here, MyPath I couldnt able to access. I want to use the MyPath variable and fetch the values, Can someone please help me with this
````

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], not snippets of code taken out of context. Also state which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Comment: The current version of XSLT is version 3.0, it has an `xsl:evaluate` element to evaluate XPath expressions. It is supported in current versions of e.g. Saxon (SaxonJS 2 for JavaScript and Node.js, Saxon 10 HE .NET for .NET framework, SaxonC 12.4 for C/C++ and Python and PHP, SaxonJ 11 or 12 Java).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using XSLT 3 and `xsl:evaluate`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
    <xsl:variable name="selected-items" as="item()*">
      <xsl:evaluate xpath="//Path" context-item="."/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$selected-items"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Run against an invented XML input sample

```
<root>
  <Variable Name="LC_F_DPN"> 
    <Path>//ZC_area/Block/Next_block/Variant</Path> 
    <Variable_type>DPN</Variable_type>
    <Class_name>Point</Class_name>
  </Variable>
  <ZC_area>
    <Block>
      <Next_block>
        <Variant>A</Variant>
      </Next_block>
      <Next_block>
        <Variant>B</Variant>
      </Next_block>
    </Block>
  </ZC_area>
</root>
```

that outputs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Variant>A</Variant>
<Variant>B</Variant>
```

[Online fiddle using SaxonJS 2](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20indent%3D%22yes%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22%2F%22%20name%3D%22xsl%3Ainitial-template%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avariable%20name%3D%22selected-items%22%20as%3D%22item%28%29*%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aevaluate%20xpath%3D%22%2F%2FPath%22%20context-item%3D%22.%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Avariable%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acopy-of%20select%3D%22%24selected-items%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0D%0A&input=%3Croot%3E%0A%20%20%3CVariable%20Name%3D%22LC_F_DPN%22%3E%20%0A%20%20%20%20%3CPath%3E%2F%2FZC_area%2FBlock%2FNext_block%2FVariant%3C%2FPath%3E%20%0A%20%20%20%20%3CVariable_type%3EDPN%3C%2FVariable_type%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CClass_name%3EPoint%3C%2FClass_name%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2FVariable%3E%0A%20%20%3CZC_area%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CBlock%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CNext_block%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CVariant%3EA%3C%2FVariant%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FNext_block%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CNext_block%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CVariant%3EB%3C%2FVariant%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FNext_block%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FBlock%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2FZC_area%3E%0A%3C%2Froot%3E&input-type=XML).

Comment: Could you please give me an answer for xslt 1.0

Comment: @Smiley, I am afraid as `XSLT 1.0` doesn't have an `xsl:evaluate` there is no general way; depending on your used XSLT 1.0 processor and its extension functions or its extension function API it might be possible to implement something but you would need to ask a question with specific information about the XSLT 1.0 processor the programming platform or language (eg. CSharp or Python) you use the run the XSLT transformation.

Answer (score -2):

I like using a Powershell script along with Xml Linq

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq 

$filename = 'c:\temp\test.xml'

$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($filename)

$variables = $doc.Descendants('Variable')

$lc_f_dpn = @([System.Linq.Enumerable]::Where($variables,  [Func[object,boolean]]{ param($x) $x[0].Attribute('Name').Value -eq 'LC_F_DPN'}))
$path = $lc_f_dpn[0].Element('Path').value
$path
```